# Where are these garlands?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Frank had laughed out loud when he saw the portrait. A delicate Marie
>   Villette Lameraux sat in front of a painted backdrop of Mount Olympus
>   in some long-ago photographer’s studio, her girlish personage
>   **festooned with garlands from the swirling braids over her ears to the
>   loopy ribbons draped between rosettes on her gown**. She stared grimly
>   at the camera.

from *Loving Frank* by Nancy Horan

I can't picture this sentence. I can understand that she is decorated with garlands but how? From the top of her ears to somewhere around the upper part of her dress?

Comment: The *start* is mentioned and not the *end*. So she's adorned with garlands right from her top of the head to her ears and running down to her gown. But if we apply some logic, no garlands run down up to waist or thighs! So, my *guess* is the decoration is from that braid to ears to somewhere around the bosom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a list, not one garland. The girl is adorned is several places. Let me break down the qoute:

> her girlish personage festooned with garlands
>
> - from the swirling braids over her ears
> - to the loopy ribbons draped between rosettes on her gown

Meaning she has complicatedly braided hair and her dress has elaborate ribbon details.

The overall effect reminds the observer of her being hung with garlands, like an excessively decorated room. Just a general "too much" effect, not literally being hung with garlands.

Note that he explicitly mentions "some long-ago photographer's studio", and "a painted backdrop", so we are talking about a fashion style from possibly the early days of portrait photography - that would be the early 20th century, a bit earlier if other techniques like daguerrotypie were used. People would put much effort into their attire and had to sit very still, explaining the grim facial expression of the subject.

Comment: I would have more confidence in your not implausible reading if the original had read "*seemed to be* festooned with garlands..."